# Hit testing on many objects Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, hittest

I am making a simulation that involves particles dynamically added to the stage (lots of circles). When these circles collide (which are actually movieclips) they need to rebound (momentum switched). I have no problem with the physics but do not know how to efficiently check for collisions. It boils down to being able to 1) Check if a particle is colliding and 2) Getting which other particle (object) is involved in the collision?

I would ideally like particles to be able to check for their own collisions and adjust their own momentum, not just some meaty `Render()` function running on every frame. How could this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficient collision detection, you will want to use something called a binary tree. Essentially, instead of checking every single pixel of every single circle against every single pixel of every single circle, you first check if it is even reasonable that two circles are touching. This is done by repeatedly dividing the map into quarters. If two circles aren't even in the same quadrant of the screen, they won't be touching.

Implementation, however, is difficult, and unless you're purposefully giving yourself a challenge, use a library so you don't reinvent the wheel. You can use Box2D, a physics engine, or Flixel, a game engine.

Comment: if(object.x+width > minX && object.x-width < maxX && blah){ if(divides < 15){ minX += (maxX - minX) / 2 } } does not seem hard..

Answer (score 0):

http://troygilbert.com/2009/08/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-revisited/

This is a link to an as3 class providing Pixel-Perfect Collision Detection. Download link provided on the site. Hope this helps.

The author also links to another solution:

http://coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5

Answer (score 0):

If you care about speed and optimization, I would suggest you go with [Box2D](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/&ei=QZzOTpCtE8rw0gGW98w-&usg=AFQjCNGbasjPzu1X027Jw7HAzeX4EGqRhg&sig2=9SxNPgMDw6SPXFuwKAqT4g). There are many examples for you to get started and doing what you're suggesting on it is actually quite simple.

Comment: This looks like a great option if one were going to use a library.

Comment: My hint to you, do not implement something as complex as physical behavior and collision detection by yourself, rely on proved, working optimized libraries that have been used, optimized, and debugged by a large amount of developers. Besides, you can include the source of the library on your code, you don't need to use a swc or anything.

Comment: If I were under contract etc I would certainly do what you are suggesting, I am however just trying to play around with flash (installed a couple of days ago) and so am deliberately doing things from first principles - I do not need the result.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the Box2D, you can still use a recursive function to make a binary search and split the search into quadrants repeatedly until you either find a collision in the element of the array or you don't